# iOS Core Data - How to avoid crash when many context save at same time?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency

I try to avoid crash when many contexts save at same time.

The following class has one operation queue that operate only one work at same time. It has three context. First, defaultContext is main queue type, this is not directly updated and is only visible to the user. Other two contexts is localContext and externalContext.

LocalContext is for user's schedule addition and external Context is for external schedule update like cloud sync. Local context and external context is child of defaultContext and set it's automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent property to true. Even if user update and external update are implemented at same time. Since they run sequentially in the same queue, there is no data loss.

It works great when data input is small. But app gets slower when too much data is coming in. Is there any better way?

Here's my code.

```
class DataController {

    static let shared = DataController()

    var schedules: [Schedule] = []

    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer

    let persistentContainerQueue = OperationQueue()

    private init() {
        persistentContainerQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataConcurrency")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    lazy var defaultContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        [unowned self] in
        self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }()

    lazy var localContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        [unowned self] in
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = self.defaultContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return context
    }()

    lazy var externalContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        [unowned self] in
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = self.defaultContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return context
    }()

    func enqueueCoreDataOperation(context: NSManagedObjectContext, changeBlock: @escaping () -> (NSManagedObjectContext)) {
        persistentContainerQueue.addOperation {
            let changedContext = changeBlock()

            guard changedContext.hasChanges else {
                return
            }

            changedContext.performAndWait({
                do {
                    try changedContext.save()

                    if let parentContext = changedContext.parent {
                        do {
                            try parentContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            fatalError()
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    fatalError()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func addSchedule(title: String, date: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let changeBlock: () -> (NSManagedObjectContext) = {
            let schedule = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Schedule", into: context) as! Schedule

            schedule.title = title
            schedule.date = date

            return context
        }

        enqueueCoreDataOperation(context: context, changeBlock: changeBlock)
    }

    func updateSchedule(schedule: Schedule, modifiedTitle: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        let scheduleInContext = context.object(with: schedule.objectID) as! Schedule

        let changeBlock: () -> (NSManagedObjectContext) = {
            scheduleInContext.title = modifiedTitle

            return context
        }

        enqueueCoreDataOperation(context: context, changeBlock: changeBlock)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could batch up the incoming data into smaller batches so each operation takes less time and add a priority to the operations so cloud based changes have a lower priority. Then they will no longer block the other changes.  But I strongly suspect that you are doing something wrong in you import operation that is making take too long. Are you doing a fetch for each imported entity?  Please share that code.

Comment: This is my entire code.
https://github.com/sohn126/CoreDataConcurrency

I forced a lot of data into two contexts at the same time in 'viewDidAppear'. In this case, the UI response is slower when scrolling the table view.